# Applying matplotlib rcParams to existing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I have a figure that I've unpickled from a file I generated earlier, but I'd like to use a different set of rcParams from those that were used when the figure was first created.  I'd to update the figure to look as though I'd created it with the new defaults rather than the old ones.

Is there a simple way of applying the new rcParams to the existing figure without the tedium of having to call lots of individual methods?

Something like this:

```
figure = pickle.load(open('figure', 'r'))
setrcParams(figure, newrcParams) # ???
figure.savefig('new-figure.png')
```

Comment: Due to a fact, that `pickle.dump()` conserves a <<_state_>> of an object, not it's genesis-path, and due to the mechanics of `rc*` configuring resources defaults for their next call(s), it seems your wish requires either to save a full transaction rollback/rollforward journal with all relevant data-inputs of the `figure` genesis, so as to be able to just change `rc*` ex-ante, at the beginning of time, and roll-forward using the new setting, or you will have to invent an iterator, to change `figure` ex-post, which may ( if not will ) have to change also many data-related elements.

Comment: Not currently possible as the lookup of rcparamas happens at artist creation time not draw time.  The 'easiest' way to do this is to save your figures as scripts so you can just re-run the script with the new rcparams.  Going back through and changing the style properties after the fact is impossible because there is no way to tell if an artist is blue because that is the default color or because the user explicitly made it blue.  Anything involving color cycle is even worse.

Comment: Thanks – I thought it might not be possible.  I'll have to refactor the plotting logic into a script or function or something.  I wanted to avoid this because there are many different plots with are large and complicated inputs.